# Sagepay API - Simulate rejected payments?

Tags: opayo

I'm testing an app which accepts payments through Sagepay.
It all seems to be working OK but I would like to test various types of non-successful responses in the Sagepay sandbox.

For example, each test I have done so far has returned a status of OK. It is also possible to receive statuses like REJECTED, NOTAUTHED, INVALID etc

Is it possible to simulate these responses in some way?

Entering incorrect details repeatedly just returns me to the failure URL I specify in the API settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you login to your simulator account on Sagepay via https://test.sagepay.com/simulator/ you can tell it which responses to return. You can instruct it to return random responses, or MALFORMED, INVALID, ERROR, NOTAUTHED, REJECTED, 3DAUTH.

Unfortunately you have to change these through the admin panel and then they apply for each transaction rather than using different details to trigger different responses.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Steve's answer, if you use the SERVER integration you can click different buttons to SIMUALATE (on the SIMULATOR server) a reply from SagePay gateway.